# Need help tracking down short story/excerpt about pain as a cultural practice

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

So, what I can remember is that there are two protagonists: 1 male, 1 female. He is from another culture, and is visiting(?) a place where people practice enduring pain as a...meditation or something? Does this ring a bell for anyone? I feel like it might have been in a fantasy anthology or something of that nature, and if I had to guess wouldn't be older than 5-10 years. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Feel free to take the [Science Fiction & Fantasy tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand our site better. You can also visit [How to ask a good question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) together with this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/) and subsequently add more details to your question so that it will be easier for others to find the book you are searching for.

Comment: Could be http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yuuzhan_Vong from the Star Wars Extended Universe "Yuuzhan Vong culture was centered on sacrifice and their gods, although warriors in particular were centered on the philosophy of pain."

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80961/short-story-about-aliens-who-use-torture-to-communicate-prove-trustworthiness/80966#80966 ?

Comment: Can it be Robert Sheckley's The Victim from Space? In that story, a writer from Earth visits a planet where a premature death is considered something to be deserved. Especially virtouous people deserve especially painful death.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may be looking for [Aldous Huxley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldous_Huxley)'s utopian themed *[Island](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?17419)*.

(Quotes from the plot summary in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_(Huxley_novel)) as my copy is packed away.)

There is significant use of meditation and hypnotism for pain control in the work:

> when a local boy and girl notice him and take him for medical treatment to their grandfather, Dr. Robert MacPhail. Dr. Robert and a young man named Murugan Mailendra carry Farnaby to Robert's house for a surprisingly successful hypnotherapy session led by Susila, Robert's daughter-in-law and the mother of the two children.

and

> Dr. Robert recounts the island's history, including how his own Scottish grandfather, Dr. Andrew MacPhail, was called to the island over a century ago to treat the Old Raja's facial tumour using both trance-based mesmerization and actual surgery; this first brought scientific practices and the English language into Palanese culture.

The story is told mainly from the point of view of a male protagonist—Farnaby—but includes significant stretches where he interacts with a female character either one on one or in a small group setting.

> Farnaby begins to establish a strong bond with Susila, who directs Farnaby to re-explore his own troubled past, including the death of his wife, Molly, on the night he confessed to cheating on her and his whole hateful childhood; Susila guides him through his painful memories. In the meantime, Susila's mother-in-law and Dr. Robert's wife, Lakshmi, is now also dying, due to cancer. One night, when the Rani urgently sends a letter to Farnaby to meet with her, he decides to finally take a stand against the exploitation of the island by Aldehyde and Dipa, and so he ignores her letter, instead going to visit the quickly-fading Lakshmi who, surrounded by her family, finally dies.

The inhabitants of the eponymous landmass practice a variant of Buddhism informed by a text written a few generations ago incorperating scientific practices into their existing spirituality

> As he recuperates, Farnaby reads Dr. Robert's copy of the Old Raja's *Notes on What's What, and What It Might be Reasonable to do about What's What*, which outlines Palanese practical philosophies for self-improvement and self-actualisation. He then tours the island's educational system, which merges the sciences, the arts, and self-control techniques with the personal search for spiritual self-fulfillment.

Though the work is generally called a novel it is quite a short one that might be better described as a novella or even a novelette, and it is not unbelievable that it could have been included in a large anthology.

Despite it's publication date in the 1960s the work has a surprisingly up-to-date feel in many aspects.